# Como ejecutar un metodo de un Activity desde un servicio, en Android?

Tags: android, activity, servicio

Hola chicos y chicas (por supuesto)

Tengo esta situacion: Tengo ejecutando un servicio en segundo plano y una actividad en primer plano, y deseo que en un momento especifico la actividad ejecute un metodo bajo demanda del servicio.

Que he hecho: Bueno la solucion que he dado es algo casi a la fuerza bruta. El servicio escribe un valor en las preferencias, y la activity que esta controlando ese valor cada 100 mS, pues necesito que sea la actualizacion instantanea; al ver el cambio de valor ejecuta el metodo

Problema de esta solucion es que consume bastantes recursos y no siempre se ejecuta como debe

Alguna idea?

**EDITADO**

esto es parte del codigo que he hecho

1-en el *servicio*

```
//...
if (needAct)
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean("needAct", true).commit();
///...
```

2-en el *onCreate* de la *activity*

```
///...
timerUiUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("needAct", false)){
                        //hacer lo que quiero hacer para actualizar la Activity
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 100, 100);
///...
```

Comment: Porque no agregar un poco de código que has realizado? o únicamente buscas  opiniones? , revisa [ask], puedes incluir un [mcve] : "Incluye solo el código suficiente para permitir a otros reproducir el problema.", saludos

Comment: Busco ideas, enfoques, codigos

Comment: Quieres llamar un metodo de un servicio en una actividad ? no te entiendo bien jaja

Comment: No al contrario desde el servicio llamar a un metodo en la actividad

Comment: bien @SanJuan y que vas actualizar en tu actividad? por que haga lo que hagas tu timertask controlara tu tiempo por que asi lo has configurado

Comment: si pero el problema es que ese metodo carga el sistema con un timer corriendo a tiempo completo  mientras la actividad esta mostrandose

Comment: @SanJuan y que realiza tu app ? cuando respondas debes etiquetar al usuario con el @ para que llegue una notificación

Comment: a disculpa @AshleyG. pero lo que haga la aplicacion no es tan importante, creo yo, esto es aplicable para cualquier app que usa un servicio del cual dependen las actualizaciones graficas

Comment: @SanJuan es importante en este caso por que si deseas que la comunidad te brinde nuevas ideas, debe conocer que quieres realizar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68561/discussion-between-san-juan-and-ashley-g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya estoy de vuelta con lo que hice.
Use un BroadcastReceiver por creer que sería mejor para el proyecto si lo mantengo con lo más simple (KISS)

Lo que hice fue:

1. Dentro de la actividad que deseo actualizar desde el servicio cree un BroadcastReceiver con el procedimiento que deseo realizar y lo adicione como objeto de la clase. Luego en el constructor registro el BroadcastReceiver y en el destructor lo desactivo.

   ```
   public class Acty_Main extends Acty_Base {
       public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
           public UpdateMailListReceiver(){
                super();
           }
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                metodoQueQuieroEjecutar();//en la activity
           }
       }
       private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
               filter.addAction("test.sanjuan.UPDATE");
               receiver = new UpdateReceiver ();
               registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
       }
       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
               if (receiver != null) {
                   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                   receiver = null;
               }
               super.onDestroy();
       }

       public vois metodoQueQuieroEjecutar(){
              Toast.makeText(context, "NEED TO UPDATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Y luego para llamarlo desde el servicio tengo que llamar al boardcast

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("test.sanjuan.UPDATE");
   context.sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
3. **Aclaracion** no deben declararlo en el manifest pues esto provocaría un error en tiempo de ejecucion de *"no empty constructor"*

Answer (score 2):

**1. Broadcast**

Puedes hacerlo con un `Broadcast`, Registras el `Broadcast` en el Activity donde deseas recivir el in intent para luego mandar a ejecutar la logica del negocio con los metodos necesarios, y desde el servicio mandas el intent mediante `sendBroadcast(intent)`

**2. EventBus**

Pudes utilizar la libreria de greenrobot para manda un `evento` desde el servicio a tu Activity.

En el Activity esperas el evento

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Logica de negocio */};
```

Y desde el Servicio envias el evento

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

No entre en detalles de codigo porque mi respuesta es una opinion.
Mi recomendacion es que utilices **EventBus** y puedas investigar mas a fondo para implementarlo en tu proyecto.

Comment: ¿Esto como lo aplicaría en el código del OP?, creo que eso sería importante. Tratamos de no responder preguntas que sean "demasiado amplias" o "basadas en opiniones", de acuerdo al [help].

Comment: ok, probaré y publicaré resultados y codigos. Thanks

Comment: gracias @Alex Gutierrez,  publico mi solucion